# How to get Delete functionality similar to iOS's native Mail app

Tags: ios, swift

I have a delete button that becomes visible when swiping, but I really like what happens in the mail app, where if you keep swiping, the delete button will be used, deleting the item.
I've seen a lot of tutorials on implementing items using

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

but I can't figure out what to use to make the button expand to the full width of the table cell. Any thoughts?

[image: A look at what I want to implement]

edit: I'd settle for just disabling swiping once the delete key has been revealed, I don't like how you can swipe the table cell to see the underlying background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using `UIScrollView` paging.

Create a `UIScrollView` and add it as a subview to your `UITableViewCell` 
(Also add size constraint to make the scrollview same size as it's parent bounds)

Now set this code for the scrollview:

```
//set scroll view
scrollview.delegate = self;
scrollview.pagingEnabled = true;
scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator  = false;
scrollview.contentSize.width = scrollview.bounds.width * 2.0;

//create delete swipe view
let deleteButton = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollview.bounds.width,0,scrollview.bounds.width * 2.0,scrollview.bounds.height))
deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let deleteLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,scrollview.bounds.width * 0.3,scrollview.bounds.height))
deleteLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
deleteLabel.text = "Delete"
deleteLabel.contentMode = .Center
deleteLabel.textAlignment = .Center
deleteButton.addSubview(deleteLabel)
scrollview.addSubview(deleteButton)
```

now the delegate function:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0{
        return;
    }

    let confirmDelete = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to delete?", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    confirmDelete.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: { (_) -> Void in
       //Delete confirmed

    }))

    confirmDelete.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (_) -> Void in
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0;
    }))

    rootViewController.presentViewController(confirmDelete, animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

this will create the next effect:

[image]

Comment: How to add the other contents on the cell ?